# PHP array_combine

Tags: php, json

Here is my PHP json output

```
[ {      
        "campaign_id": "4",   
        "date": "2017-04-01",   
        "name": "Dealoyal",   
        "iteration": "5149"   
    },   
....   
]
```

I want to make it to look like this:

```
[{   
    "date": "2017-04-01",   
    "Dealoyal": "5149"   
},...]
```

My code:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $name[] = $row['name'];
    $iteration[] = $row['iteration'];
}
$mine[]=array_combine($name, $iteration);
echo json_encode($mine,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

But this only prints the last day names and iterations , when I need all days that I choose at date range. Do I need to use for loop or maybe there is another way?

Comment: Could you explain me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `array_combine()`, you can directly create `$mine` in the `foreach`:

```
$mine = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $mine[] = array(
        'date' => $row['date'],
        $row['name'] => $row['iteration'],
    );
}
echo json_encode($mine, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```